# How to make the `yaml.dump({1}) ` output "? 1" instead of "1: null" in Python?

Tags: python, yaml, set, pyyaml

This code in Python:

```py
import yaml

data = {1}

print(yaml.dump(data))
```

prints:

```
!!set
1: null
```

Is it possible to make this output:

```
!!set
? 1
```

I think we should be able to do it, because this code:

```py
import yaml

print(yaml.safe_load("""
!!set 
? 1"""))
```

Prints:

```
{1}
```

Comment: There does not seem to be existing support for this. You'll need to create a custom `Dumper` subclass. I took a stab at doing this, but unfortunately it looks it's going to be herculean effort. There are many parts that need to be overridden, since this needs to propagate through several layers of internal representations. The number of layers of abstractions gives [enterprise fizzbuzz](https://github.com/EnterpriseQualityCoding/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition) a run for its money

Comment: That you can load something with PyYAML, doesn't mean you can dump the exact output as you loaded, because infinitely many inputs load to the same datastructure, and there is a finite number of controls over the output. BTW doing `print(yaml.dump(data))` is inefficient wrt run-time and memory usage, you should always use `yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since sets are simply mappings with null values in YAML, you can customize the output of a set object by overriding [`yaml.emitter.Emitter.expect_block_mapping`](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/155ec463f6a854ac14ccd5e2dda8017ce42a508a/lib/yaml/emitter.py#L388), the block-style emitter of a mapping event, to divert the processing to a custom handler when the event tag is of a set, where the processing logics would be similar to how a regular mapping event is processed by [`expect_block_mapping_key`](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/155ec463f6a854ac14ccd5e2dda8017ce42a508a/lib/yaml/emitter.py#L395C9-L395C33) method, but would force a non-simple key output with a `?` indicator, and then force the subsequent value state handler to directly move on to the key state handler to avoid the output of a `null` value:

```
import yaml

class SetDumper(yaml.Dumper):
    def expect_block_mapping(self):
        super().expect_block_mapping()
        if self.event.tag == 'tag:yaml.org,2002:set':
            self.state = self.expect_first_block_set_key

    def expect_first_block_set_key(self):
        return self.expect_block_set_key(first=True)

    def expect_block_set_key(self, first=False):
        if not first and isinstance(self.event, yaml.MappingEndEvent):
            self.indent = self.indents.pop()
            self.state = self.states.pop()
        else:
            self.write_indent()
            self.write_indicator('?', True, indention=True)
            self.states.append(self.expect_block_set_value)
            self.expect_node(mapping=True)

    def expect_block_set_value(self):
        self.state = self.expect_block_set_key
```

so that:

```
import sys
yaml.dump({1}, sys.stdout, Dumper=SetDumper)
```

outputs:

```
!!set
? 1
```

and that:

```
yaml.dump({1: {1, 2}, 2: {3, 4}}, sys.stdout, Dumper=SetDumper)
```

outputs:

```
1: !!set
  ? 1
  ? 2
2: !!set
  ? 3
  ? 4
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/PrettyGoldRelationaldatabase

Answer (score 0):

If you can upgrade to `ruamel.yaml`, which gives you YAML 1.2 support as well as preservation
of comments when loading-dumping, you can easily achieve your output.

By default as Python `set` is dumped as a tagged mapping with as null values the empty string:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

   
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = {1}
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

this gives:

```
!!set
1:
```

If you round-trip your expected output, you see that `ruamel.yaml` preserves the format
that you want:

```py
yaml_str = """\
!!set
? 1   # only one, lonely, member
"""
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

this dumps the same as the input:

```
!!set
? 1   # only one, lonely, member
```

Inspecting the `type(data)` will reveal that this is a `CommentedSet()` instance,
and you can use that knowledge to create the output from scratch:

```py
data = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedSet({42})
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

giving:

```
!!set
? 42
```